# Regex for double value in Swift 2

Tags: regex, swift2, ios9

What's the new regex for a double, such as "123.45"

I've use the old ones `[0-9]{1,}.[0-9]{1,}|[0-9]{1,}` and `\\d+(\\.\\d+)?`. They work, but I can't use the `.`

When I tap `.` on the keyboard it doesn't appear in the field

I tested this on XCode 7 GM Seed - iOS 9 - iPad Air 2 Simulator

UPDATE:

```
    extension String {
        func stringsMatchingRegularExpression(expression: String) -> [String] {
            if let range = self.rangeOfString(expression, options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil, locale: nil) {
                return [self[range]] + self[range.endIndex..<self.endIndex].stringsMatchingRegularExpression(expression)
            }
            return []
        }
}
```

This is the extension that I use and this function that removes everything except the regex:

```
func onlyDoubleUse(textField: AnyObject){
    let field = textField.object! as! UITextField
    let subStringArray = field.text!.stringsMatchingRegularExpression("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")
    if(subStringArray.count>0){
        if(subStringArray[0] != ""){
            field.text = subStringArray[0]
        }else{
            field.text = ""
        }
    }else{
        field.text = ""
    }
}
```

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "onlyDoubleUse:", name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification, object: theTextField)`

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't appear in the field"? The regexes are both correct (except `.` should be escaped using `\\.` in the first example)

Comment: The first one seems unnecessary complex. Why not use `\\d{3}(\\.\\d{2})`? Works only if you want exactly 5 numbers. Else use your second regex.

Comment: Check the update. The dot - `.` is not working with this regex test it please I already test it on iPad 2 and all simulators on XCode 7 GM Seed even on the beta versions 4 and 5 doesn't working. YOU CAN'T TYPE (DOT=`.`) IN THE TEXT FIELD WITH THIS REGEX!

Comment: You can't type `.` (only a dot) but you can type: one or more digits, optionally followed a dot and one or more digits. List all the options that you should be able to type.

Comment: I know but there is some bug that I told you. Test to see. It can't be typed 23.4, 1.2, 531.53 the dot is not appear in the field when you click on the button in simulator's keyboard or on the iMac's keyboard...